# Is BlackBerry 9500 the only model with a clickable touchscreen? (and other questions)

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, touchscreen, blackberry-storm

As far as I remember, the 9500 simulator processes left mouse clicks as clicks on the clickable touchscreen (the feature of the 9500) and right mouse clicks as touches on the touchscreen.
I have some questions.

Is BlackBerry 9500 the only model with a clickable touchscreen?
If the 9550 model does not have this clickable touchscreen and the 9550 simulator still processes left and right clicks differently, - is it an error of the simulator?

The 9800 simulator processes left and right clicks the same way - is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the 9500 has a clickable screen.  Later touchscreen devices are not clickable.